# Where should I make a python-twitter API call in my Django/React webapp

Tags: django, reactjs, django-rest-framework, react-redux, twitterapi-python

I'm creating a full stack web app using react, react-redux, and Django-rest, and I need to make an API call using the python-twitter api, then display the data from this request in my react frontend. The flow of control will be a user enters their twitter username in the frontend, which needs to trigger an API call using this username in the Django backend. Then the data from this call needs to be fed back into the React frontend using redux. Where should I be making this API call in the Django backend?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are wanting to use django and python to do it? It seems like a bit over the top for just making an API call and displaying results. This could be easily achieved with just a simple function in React.

Comment: @RobB Just using Django so I can use python for the python-twitter library to make the twitter API call.

Answer (score 0):

You can make authentication and configuration of the `python-twitter` in `Django Backend`. Then you can simply call the `API's` from the `react` web application. I have made for it. Here you go: [python-twitter boiler-plate](https://github.com/MirzaBaig715/simple-python-twitter). Hope this helps :)